# MySQL select distinct rows and the latest one based on timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

Please help us we have trouble to get the last recently added distinct row from one of our mysql table and the query includes a cross join too

The scenario is a feedback table and queried every 30 seconds to reply them back.
we need to get the latest distinct rows for glancing.

TABLE_1 - PK = id

```
id | name  
1  | Jhon  
2  | Smith
```

TABLE_2 - Composite = stamp,id

```
stamp      | id  | feed                               | feed_for
1467898676 |  1  |  hi                                |  2
1467898678 |  1  |  welcome                           |  2
1467898679 |  2  |  hello                             |  1
1467898680 |  2  |  am intrested in your product      |  1
```

now we only need the distinct rows from table_2 and the latest one the join we peformed is as shown

```
select a.id,a.name,b.stamp,b.feed 
from TABLE_1 a, TABLE_2 b 
where b.feed_for=2 and a.id=b.id 
group by a.id 
order by b.stamp desc
```

It gets unique rows but not the latest one. Please help what would be a efficient and working query

the query i have posted is the fastest one for us(tested on a 2.9 million row table) takes 0.013 secs and its about joining two table while getting unique latest row from one table and joining to get other infos on other table

Comment: Please learn to use ANSI JOIN syntax instead of implicit joins.

Comment: There isnt any question explains this scenario and the solutions are contrasting, thank you

Comment: I don't see how your question is significantly different from the thousands of other similar questions about getting the latest row for each group.

Comment: they are inevitably slow sir

Comment: Add an index on `(id, stamp)` and I think you should be able to speed it up. `(stamp, id)` is not useful for getting the latest timestamp within each group.

Comment: Well our team solved it, thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: this is what we came up with and working very well for now `select a.id,a.name,b.stamp,b.feed,max(b.stamp)
from TABLE_1 a, TABLE_2 b 
where b.feed_for=2 and a.id=b.id 
group by a.id 
order by b.stamp desc` adding max worked

Comment: That won't always return the `feed` from the same row with `max(stamp)`.

Comment: @Barmar I'm having a terribly difficult time finding a solution to this question. The linked duplicate does not involve two tables as this question does. Could you point me to a solution for this question, exactly as asked? The only difference for me is I also need to test that `b.stamp` is less than a specific value. Thanks!

Comment: Here's another question that joins 2 tables and finds the max record per group: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299205/mysql-join-select-max-for-all-record/33363569#33363569