# Mysql join select max for all record

Tags: mysql

I am unable to map the record as my expectation.

**Doc Table**

```
-------+-------------------
doc_id | doc_title         
-------+-------------------
1      | My book
-------+-------------------
2      | My sec Book 
--------------------------
```

**Doc details Table**

```
-----------+--------------+-----------------------
fk_doc_id  |  doc_version |  submit_date
-----------+--------------+-----------------------
1          |   1          |  2015-10-25 14:32:01
-----------+--------------+-----------------------
1          |   2          |  2015-10-26 13:00:01
-----------+--------------+-----------------------
1          |   3          |  2015-10-27 09:00:00 
--------------------------+-----------------------
2          |   1          |  2015-10-25 11:15:01
-----------+--------------+-----------------------
2          |   2          |  2015-10-26 10:00:00
--------------------------+-----------------------
```

Question: How do I join this two tables to get each documents with the latest version doc info? even though I get the latest version but the row info which is not correct.

So far I have tried this query

```
SELECT *, max(doc_version) AS latest_version
FROM d_doc
JOIN d_doc_dtl ON d_doc.doc_id = d_doc_dtl.fk_doc_id
GROUP BY d_doc.doc_id;
```

My expected result is

```
--------+--------------+----------------+--------------------
doc_id  |  doc_title   | latest_version | submit_date
--------+--------------+----------------+--------------------
1       |  My book     | 3              | 2015-10-27 09:00:00
--------+--------------+----------------+--------------------
2       | My sec book  | 2              | 2015-10-26 10:00:00
----------------------------------------+--------------------
```

but my result is

```html
--------+--------------+----------------+--------------------
doc_id  |  doc_title   | latest_version | submit_date
--------+--------------+----------------+--------------------
1       |  My book     | 3              | 2015-10-25 14:32:01
--------+--------------+----------------+--------------------
2       | My sec book  | 2              | 2015-10-25 11:15:01
----------------------------------------+--------------------
```

NOTE: the submit_date which is no correct.

Comment: Doesn't this query work as you expect? If so, what is the result now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should work as you expect. It selects latest document versions in inner subquery and than joins it with documents.

```
SELECT d.doc_id,
       d.doc_title,
       dtl.doc_version latest_version,
       dtl.submit_date
  FROM d_doc d
 INNER JOIN (SELECT dt.*
               FROM d_doc_dtl dt
              INNER JOIN (SELECT fk_doc_id, MAX(doc_version) doc_version 
                            FROM d_doc_dtl
                           GROUP BY fk_doc_id) dm
                 ON dt.fk_doc_id = dm.fk_doc_id
                AND dt.doc_version = dm.doc_version) dtl
    ON d.doc_id = dtl.fk_doc_id
```

You get wrong results because you selected only max(version), but date as it is not in group by clause can contain any value. First you need to get records containing latest version as shown above.

Comment: Thanks for solution~ i make it!! also i found this article is very useful and well explanation. http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d_doc.doc_id, d_doc.doc_title, max_table.latest_version
FROM d_doc JOIN (
select fk_doc_id, max(doc_version) as latest_version from d_doc_dtl group by fk_doc_id
) as max_table ON d_doc.doc_id = max_table.fk_doc_id
```

Comment: It is possible that this code is a good solution, however without explanation it is not really helpful. Can you please explain why or how this code helps? Please read [answer] in [help] for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, instead of

```
SELECT *, max(doc_version) AS latest_version
```

Use this

```
SELECT d_doc.*, max(doc_version) AS latest_version
```

What you were doing by selecting * is getting all the results after the table is joined and you only wanted the original table results.

Comment: sry for late reply~ thanks for solution but it does't work for me. i had update my question for better understanding~

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from doc_table , doc_version  where exists( select 
        max(version_id)
    from
        doc_version vert
    where
        (doc_table .DOC_ID = vert.VERSION_DOC_ID) ) group by doc_id;
```

You can try something like this.

Comment: sry for late reply~ thanks for solution. but i don't understand you query, can you base on my table field? sry about that

Comment: The inner select query will give you the latest version in version table for the document later you can make a group by of doc id in first query and get the result. This could not be the exact query you are expecting but you can get an idea from it.

Comment: Thanks i will try it out~